# I am getting error "undefined reference to 'fork' "

Tags: c, fork

This program is not working on gcc......and giving an linker error..i.e. undefined reference to fork...

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<unistd.h>    

int main()  
{  
    int a=10;  
    if (a==10 && fork())  
        printf("hello");  
    else  
        printf("world");  

    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The fact that you're using `system("pause")` (a bad idea, by the way, when you can simply use `getchar()`) leads me to believe that you're running on Windows. Unless you use an emulation layer like CygWin, `fork` is not available on that platform.

To be honest, I'm not sure how you even managed to compile since Windows doesn't generally have `unistd.h` either unless perhaps you've installed SFU or MinGW (which, despite having `unistd.h` to ease the task of compiling code (less conditional compilation), does not provide more functionality than what you get with Windows).

Answer (score 2):

`fork` does not exist on Windows (except if you are using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)). Use `CreateProcess` instead.

Comment: `<unistd.h>` doesn't either. If he tried compiling it would have said can't compile anyway.

Comment: I think MinGW provides a version of `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: Another option to create new process would be `_spawnl()`.